# Inserting data into one field only

Tags: php, mysql, insert-into

I have a data table called movieTitles and each field is a title of a movie. Under each field I will be putting keywords for each movie (a word for each row), and I want to just insert those words into the field without having to query the rest of the fields.

EX.

I will be having thousands of movie titles as the field name and I will have a interface that will take words in for one movie at a time. so Lets add the words [legos, lord business, benny, will ferrell] to the field: Lego Movie. But I will be having thousands of movies and don't want to have the query:

---

```
INSERT INTO table(Fury, Lego Movie, Fight Club, Step Brothers, Anchorman) VALUES ('','legos','','','')

INSERT INTO table(Fury, Lego Movie, Fight Club, Step Brothers, Anchorman) VALUES ('','lord business','','','')

INSERT INTO table(Fury, Lego Movie, Fight Club, Step Brothers, Anchorman) VALUES ('','benny','','','')

INSERT INTO table(Fury, Lego Movie, Fight Club, Step Brothers, Anchorman) VALUES ('','will ferrell','','','')
```

---

Is there some way that I can just add one word to a field like:

---

```
INSERT INTO table(Lego Movie) VALUE ('legos')

INSERT INTO table(Lego Movie) VALUE ('lord business')

INSERT INTO table(Lego Movie) VALUE ('benny')

INSERT INTO table(Lego Movie) VALUE ('will ferrell')
```

---

I know I can do a bunch of nested loops and add buffers and stuff like that but I feel like there should be something real simple.
Anyone have an idea?

Comment: Everything about this database is completely wrong from a [database normalization perspective](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). Why would you do it this way?

Answer (score 0):

If you set default values for the other columns you can just insert one field. And, if your movie name is you PK there should be no problem.

As Jay Blanchard said, this database design is just wrong.